# (Eclipse) Decoration Calculation Error on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-13.10

when i navigate in project tree (such as open package, etc) their always show error message box :

> An internal error occurred during: "Decoration Calculation".
>   org/eclipse/jdt/internal/debug/ui/MemberActionFilter

and this is the log in /.workspace/.log :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2013-11-01 17:29:23.513
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Decoration Calculation".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/debug/ui/MemberActionFilter
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.ActionFilterAdapterFactory.getAdapter(ActionFilterAdapterFactory.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.AdapterManager.getAdapter(AdapterManager.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.PlatformObject.getAdapter(PlatformObject.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.util.Util.getAdapter(Util.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionExpression$ObjectStateExpression.getActionFilter(ActionExpression.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionExpression$ObjectStateExpression.preciselyMatches(ActionExpression.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionExpression$ObjectStateExpression.isEnabledFor(ActionExpression.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionExpression$SingleExpression.isEnabledFor(ActionExpression.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionExpression.isEnabledFor(ActionExpression.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratorDefinition.isEnabledFor(DecoratorDefinition.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratorManager.getDecoratorsFor(DecoratorManager.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.getDecoratorsFor(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.getDecorations(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.ensureResultCached(DecorationScheduler.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.run(DecorationScheduler.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

FYI, I'am using Eclipse for Java EE (Kepler)
on Ubuntu 13.10 64bit

sorry for my english :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with kepler on Debian Jessie.
But i realized that eclipse started with a second flying window i detached in my last session to compare to classes. I told eclipse to "Reset Perspective" in Windows menu and restarted. That did the trick.

Comment: Reset perspective + restarting worked for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Close to Eclipse
Copy to yout project (projects) from workspace to temp dir
Remove ./workspace/.metadata
Run Eclipse and import yout project with copy source code